# New additional fields in java.lang.Thread, what is the idea?

Tags: java, java-8, thread-local

In Java 8, `java.lang.Thread` class got 3 new fields:

```
/** The current seed for a ThreadLocalRandom */
@sun.misc.Contended("tlr")
long threadLocalRandomSeed;

/** Probe hash value; nonzero if threadLocalRandomSeed initialized */
@sun.misc.Contended("tlr")
int threadLocalRandomProbe;

/** Secondary seed isolated from public ThreadLocalRandom sequence */
@sun.misc.Contended("tlr")
int threadLocalRandomSecondarySeed;
```

as it said in Javadoc for being exclusively managed by class `java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom`.

Furthermore, in `ThreadLocalRandom` they are used in very freakish way:

```
SEED = UNSAFE.objectFieldOffset
    (tk.getDeclaredField("threadLocalRandomSeed"));
PROBE = UNSAFE.objectFieldOffset
    (tk.getDeclaredField("threadLocalRandomProbe"));
SECONDARY = UNSAFE.objectFieldOffset
    (tk.getDeclaredField("threadLocalRandomSecondarySeed"));
```

(the same code piece can be met also in `LockSupport` class).

and then this offsets are used internally in several `java.concurrent` places.

What is the idea? Why these fields are places inside `java.lang.Thread`? Why not inside `ThreadLocalRandom`?

Comment: No idea about this one - I would have / actually have had an answer to your previous question regarding the `"tlr"`.

Comment: @luk2302 Great answer, I many thanks to you, but somebody has downvoted that my question, so I have to delete it. I'm really sorry about this.

Comment: Downvotes are no reason to delete question or answers, I gave you an upvote for example, making it a 0 score.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are internal fields. Explanations can only come from JDK developers themselves. I was able to find a [post](http://openjdk.5641.n7.nabble.com/Improving-ThreadLocalRandom-and-related-classes-td111088.html) about this from Doug Lea dated January 2013, that explains the rationale behind those fields and why they are inside the `Thread` class.

> When we introduced `ThreadLocalRandom`, we conservatively
>   implemented it to use an actual `ThreadLocal`. However,
>   as it becomes more widely used, it is worth improving
>   the implementation by housing `ThreadLocalRandom` state
>   (and related bookkeeping) in class `Thread` itself.
>   This would entail three fields (16 total bytes).
>
> So I propose adding the following to class Thread:
>
> ```
> // The following three initially uninitialized fields are exclusively
> // managed by class java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.
> /** The current seed for a ThreadLocalRandom */
> long threadLocalRandomSeed;
> /** Probe hash value; nonzero if threadLocalRandomSeed initialized */
> int threadLocalRandomProbe;
> /** Secondary seed isolated from public ThreadLocalRandom sequence */
> int threadLocalRandomSecondarySeed;
> ```
>
> The reasons for doing it in this way are:
>
> 1. Uniformly faster access to `ThreadLocalRandom` state. While
>      `ThreadLocal` access is normally pretty fast already, this is
>      not only faster, it does not degrade in cases where user
>      programs create large numbers of `ThreadLocal`s, which
>      may (probabilistically) cause any given access to become
>      slower.
> 2. Smaller total footprint for any program using `ThreadLocalRandom`.
>      Three fields require less space than boxing into a padded
>      `ThreadLocal` object. As `ThreadLocalRandom` becomes widely used
>      within JDK itself, this includes just about all programs.
> 3. Further time/space savings for `java.util.concurrent ForkJoinPool`,
>      `ConcurrentHashMap`, `LongAdder`, `ConcurrentSkipList`, and other
>      classes that could use this form of the unified `ThreadLocalRandom`
>      bookkeeping rather than their own special-purpose `ThreadLocal`s
>      as they now do.

Comment: Thank you a lot for paper link, +1. But this solution looks as slightly messy, don't you think so?

Comment: Additionally, I do not really understand, why these fields can not be placed inside `ThreadLocalRandom` class?

Comment: @Andremoniy I'm honestly not in a position to judge technical solutions made by the JDK devs themselves. The reason they were added to Thread probably comes down to this comment by Doug Lea: "But mostly: The space for "permanent" thread-locals
needs to be placed somewhere; why not choose the
place that presents the fewest logistics problems?
Note that class java.lang.Thread is only the visible
tip of the iceberg of per-thread storage on systems.
so adding 16bytes is all but undetectable."

Comment: @Andremoniy: if these fields were declared in `ThreadLocalRandom`, you needed a distinct `ThreadLocalRandom` instance per thread which required `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` to use a `ThreadLocal` variable, which was deemed to be not efficient enough. Thus, `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` returns a singleton instance, which is cheap, but implies that it can’t host these fields which have to be distinct per thread. Thus, these fields are stored in the `Thread` instance *given the current implementation*.

Answer (score 1):

I will resurrect this by adding a small answer too, since I've just hit this in LongAdder and there's a great video where Shipilev explains this in simple words (it is in russian), here is the link: [ThreadLocalRandom](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0dGLFtRR9c&t=68m)

For the case of ForkJoinPool, it needs to put tasks into a queue and remove from a queue, which queue exaclty is solved via a good [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).

This prng has to be very fast and highly scalable. Well, java has one in place: ThreadLocalRandom. For these fields to be put into ThreadLocalRandom, it needed a ThreadLocal, which in turn internally uses a ThreadLocalMap(think HashMap).

ThreadLocal.get (think HashMap#get) is much slower then getting these fields directly from Thread.