# What is the difference between (a != b) and (a != (a = b)?

Tags: java, comparison, operators

In a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319047/why-concurrentlinkedqueue-source-code-use-to-check-for-tail/48319214#48319214), we found the following piece of code:

```
// p, t, q and tail are Node<E> objects.
p = (p != t && t != (t = tail)) ? t : q;
```

Omitting the context of the question, I am interested in the following behavior:

```
t != (t = tail)
```

Considering those are the same type of objects, whatever the type. Is there any difference between this and:

```
t != tail
```

Or am I missing something crucial in the comparison mechanism ?

---

**EDIT**

If anyone wonders, this is found in the [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) class from `java.util`, line 352.

Comment: single '=' is an affectation operator. this is a twisted way to assign t to tail and then checking for its reference inequality to tail (which would always be false at this point)

Comment: The difference is, in first t gets value of tail, in second not.

Comment: @spi, considering this is something we found in the `ConcurrencyLinkedQueue` class from `java.util`, this does not sound very reassuring.

Comment: @YassineBadache I hate seeing those constructs in any code. Having it in core java is indeed not much reassuring :)

Comment: @spi generally these constructs are petty smart, like doing a single read for example... don't judge the code used by millions all over the world.

Comment: My opinion does not matter much. But I bet everybody here would agree it is a pain for maintenance. You spare nanoseconds in the cost of readability which I find really awfull.

Comment: @spi first of all, tagging someone via `@` is the way to get someone's attention. it's sometimes about nano-seconds, sometimes about a correct way *at all*. Things are harder then you might think: http://jeremymanson.blogspot.md/2008/12/benign-data-races-in-java.html

Comment: @spi and if you think that getting those nano-seconds for java is not important, think about this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41021171/1059372 where fields have been moved to squeeze those nanoseconds. for a library as java this *is* important

Comment: Interesting lecture, I will give it a shot. Thank you Eugene !

Comment: @YassineBadache np, I added that as an answer too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48322642/1059372

Comment: @Eugene you're right, in a lib that matters. Maybe I underevaluated the cleverness here, but I still think anybody doing it without 1) a deep understand of what's going on and 2) a real need to this and 3) no comments to explain _why_ it's doing that way should rewrite it with a more easy to understand sequence of statements. Maintenance is really important for me, as it takes more than 80% of my time. Maybe at Oracle you are not that concerned about it, but 99% of standards programmers are.

Comment: @spi that is correct, but we *are* talking in the context of Oracle lib after all; otherwise I do agree.

Comment: I agree on the commenting part. They should have added a comment, explaining *why* this choice. It may handle some precious information about the behavior of the component.

Comment: @YassineBadache in this case `java.util.concurrent.XXX` would be 100x bigger due to the comments and let's not forget that it was *you* that looked there; no one has to document *internal details*

Comment: @YassineBadache To be fair: The concurrent data structures are pretty well commented. Often with an elaborate `/* non-javadoc */` comment at the top and `/** JavaDocs */` even at `private` fields, and several detailed `//inline` comments. The fact that they are hard to understand nevertheless on the one hand is due to the complexity of the topic. On the other hand, ... (continued...)

Comment: ... the developers sometimes use certain "patterns" that lead to smaller bytecode. The latter is IMHO questionable, because maintaining such code can be a nightmare, and considering the JIT, I doubt that the benefits outweigh the hassle. But regarding this specific example: Have a look at an [earlier version of the `offer` method](https://github.com/dmlloyd/openjdk/blob/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java#L217) - this was still *far* simpler and more readable.

Comment: For the curious: The step from the "simple" implementation to this "complex" one in the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` seems (!) to stem from this changeset: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/rev/902486a8e414#l3.202

Comment: @Marco13 this is an excellent find, thank you. Now I dp agree that the simpler offer is *much* more readable. I just wonder what would be the reason for such a drastic change., It has to be more than bytecode, really, this is not convincing enough. It might be just Doug Lea's preffered way of writing code

Comment: @Eugene His style and this extreme micro-optimization has already raised [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2785964/3182664), as you know. The previous version of the code (using the `continue retry;`) is also something that I'd never accept in a code review, but this area of the codebase is *veery* special and delicate. I just think (or maybe just *hope*? - at least: I have to assume) that Doug Lea has deeply profound technical reasons to do it exactly like that. In some cases (like this one), I'd be curious to hear them, though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t != (t = tail)
```

is equivalent to

```
oldt = t;
t = tail;
... oldt != t...
```

i.e. the original value of `t` is compared to `tail` and in addition `t` is assigned the value of `tail`.

It's a short way of writing

```
if (t != tail) {
    t = tail;
}
```

Comment: I get it better. Oracle developers sometimes have some weird ways to handle things. I wonder if they had their reasons. Thank you !

Comment: exactly wrong.  the order of operations in your code is backwards

Comment: @AbdulAhad I see what you claimed in your answer, but if you were right, the condition would always be evaluated to false (unless some other thread changed the value of t after the assignment and before the condition), which is not true. Try to run `int t=1; int tail=2;if (t != (t = tail)) System.out.println ("not equal");`. You'll see "not equal" is printed.

Comment: @Eran well it seems that this is not entirely *the same* thing... https://stackoverflow.com/a/48322642/1059372 sometimes this matters quite a lot: http://jeremymanson.blogspot.md/2008/12/benign-data-races-in-java.html. But again, I have not dived too much into the OP's questions code to be *very sure*

Comment: Why would you check if `t != tail` before setting t to tail? Why not just assign t to tail either way?

Comment: @Anthony usually there's some additional action you want to perform only if t != tail.

Comment: I think what you said about the "short way" is at least misleading (if not just wrong). The assignment `t=tail` **always** happens, and not only if they are not equal. The point is that the condition checks *whether* the value did change due to that assignment. This is somewhat clearer in the first part of your answer, but the `...` could be replaced by a proper `if`. EDIT: (Regarding your first comment above) : I think the whole point of this is to detect whether another thread modified the `tail`.

Comment: @Marco13 pretty darn happy it wasn't just me thinking this way. Since this is a concurrent data structure, someone might have already removed tail while you were looking at it. As far as I understand this is what this code does

Answer (score 3):

The first code:

```
t != (t = tail)
```

will assign tail to t then compare t with the new value

the second one will compare t to tail

Answer (score -3):

Note: the other answer is what Java is actually doing

```
synchronized(x) {
     if(t != (t = tail));
}
```

is equivalent to

```
synchronized(x) {
    t = tail;

    if(t != t) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

basically, a reference to what is assigned is returned by the ( ) operator

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer a = 1;
        Integer b = 2;

        if(a != (b = a)) {
            System.out.println("however, there is an issue with a != (a = b), Java bug");
        } else {
            System.out.println("assignment first, obvious by inspection");
        }
    }
}
```

However, the same code works in C.  If I had to guess, this is unintentional in Java, any departure from C on something like this is **folly**.  Oracle probably isn't looking forward to deprecating it, assuming it is a unintentional bug, which it probably is.

I'll get to it the next time I talk to them.  I'm still mad at them regarding that whole Abode fiasco at the DOD related to setting my mom's homepage to ask.com in collusion with Apple Incorporated.  Apple fixed iTunes in less than a week after I had to click the thing over 400 times in order to retry after re-download failures of my daughter's video library though, so the issue is limited to Oracle.  It affected Microsoft as well so everyone was mad about it.

```
#include <iostream>

static int ref = 0;

class t {
public:
    t(int x) : x(x), r(ref) { ref++; }
    t(const t& o) : x(o.x), r(o.r) { }
    t& operator=(const t& o) { x = o.x; r = o.r; return *this; }
    bool operator!=(const t& o) const { return r != o.r; }
private:
    int x;
    int r;
};

int main() {
    t a(1);
    t b(2);

    if(a != (a = b)) {
        std::cout <<  "assignment\n";
    } else {
        std::cout <<  "no assignment\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hummm actually not. The first reference to t that is used is evaluated before the assignation on the right side of the equals sign. I thought like you first, but this code proves it to be wrong: ```Object p=null, t="t", tail="tail", q="q"; p = (p != t && t != (t = tail)) ? t : q; System.out.println(p); // show "tail"```

Comment: Still no luck. Try again :)